# how to use html to post multipart/form-data

Tags: html, multipart, form-data

I have  form, I want to post through multipart/form-data.
How to use html to specify each fields' type.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        New Student
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://10.128.157.12:8080/student" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  student first name: <input type="text" size="100" name="firstname" value="Michael"/><br>
  student last name: <input type="text" size="100" name="lastname" value="William"/><br>
  student age: <input type="text" size="100" name="age" value="34" /> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" autofocus="autofocus" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the question? you are already specifying the "text" type on your fields, what do you want to do?